# Disable button with javascript

Tags: javascript, button, disable

I have a button. The button works fine. After I have pressed the button, then it shall not be possible to press the button again. It will be best if the button looks diabled.

I have already tried with document.getElementById("id").disabled = true; but I can't make this work.

PHP code for the button. The code makes a list of buttons. Each button has id= 1, 2, 3 etc.

```
if($_COOKIE["sorterdb"]=='GR' || empty($_COOKIE["sorterdb"])){$dblinjer[$i]['nrlink']='<span id="para'.$i.'"></span><div class="s-12 l-12"><button type="button" id="'.$i.'" value="'.$dblinjer[$i]['loebid'].'_'.$dblinjer[$i]['tid'].'_'.$dblinjer[$i]['utcstart'].'" onclick=baadimaal("baadimaal",this)>'.$dblinjer[$i]['buttonnrsejl'].'</button></div>';}
```

javascript:

```
function baadimaal(str,el) {
    var x = el.value
    var id = el.getAttribute("id")
    
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("container"+id).innerHTML = this.responseText; //her placeres svaret, som kommer tilbage fra hide-ajax-svar filen
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "hide-ajax-svar.php?funk=" + str + "&para=" + x + "&i=" + id); //overfør str og x til hide-ajax-svar filen
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code for disable button in your snippet, you can use directly `el` like `el.disabled = true;`

Comment: Hi tipman, when you set up the disabled to true makes the button as disabled as objet. You should set an attribute to this button. buttonSelector.setAttribute('disabled',true);

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño—there is no *addAttribute*, there is [*setAttribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). The *disabled* attribute is boolean: simply setting it makes the element disabled. To set the property to false, use [*removeAttribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) or assign to it directly per *Simone's* comment.

Comment: Oh, you can also have the handler remove the click listener as well as disabling the button.

Comment: Can you please show where in the code I should set. I can't make any of the suggestions work.

Comment: I have tried with this in the beginning of the script.
```
function baadimaaldis(str,el) {
    var x = el.value
    var id = el.getAttribute("id")
    el.disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button like this:

```
<button class="button" id="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button" id="2">Button 2</button>
<button class="button" id="3">Button 3</button>
```

You can add javascript eventlistener, do the job, than disable:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button")

buttons.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

    // DO SOMETHING WHITH YOUR BUTTON
    console.log(`You've clicked on ${item.id} and now I'm gonna disable it.`)

    // disable
    item.disabled = true;
    })            
})
```

And depending on your code, maybe you should add "removeEventListener" on your button.

Comment: I can't make this work. Please be aware that I have many buttons, which each have id 1, 2, 3, etc. Please give an example on how the exact code should look like.

Comment: I've changed the code for multiple buttons.

Comment: https://codepen.io/suti1979/pen/Exwamvr

Comment: Can the code be change, so the id from the button is used? I have other button on the page which shall not be disabled. Please see my first code which describes how the button is defind. $i is just a simple counter.

Comment: It disables the exact button what you clicked on, if it has the same class or id. You can use id too like this: const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#id"), if it has the same ID. 
If it's not, you can use different eventListeners every separate id button, but that's not to elegant. ;)

Comment: Those buttons can have different ID, but same functionality. That is why best practice to group in one class.

Comment: I've changed my code once more, hopefully it's more clear now for you.

Comment: I have added your code in the bottom of my script above. When I press button first time, it is not disabled = ok. When I press the button second time it is not disabled = not ok. After that I can only press the buttons once. Why is it not disabled by the second press?

Comment: If you have a github (or something) of you code, I'll check it what's wrong with is, but my code is working like you want to, you can check it here: https://codepen.io/suti1979/pen/Exwamvr

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button's disabled property to *false* (see [Sütemény András's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70180552/257182)), but that may not work in all browsers. You can also remove the listener, however that doesn't make the button look disabled.

So a belt and braces approach is to do both, e.g.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Listener
  function clickFn() {
    console.log('I\'ve been clicked! But no more…');
    // Make button appear disabled
    this.disabled = true;
    // Remove the listener
    this.removeEventListener('click', clickFn);
  }
  // Add the listener to the button
  document.getElementById('b0').addEventListener('click', clickFn, false);
};
```

```html
<button id="b0">Click me</button>
```

Note that if using *setAttribute* as in:

```
button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

the second argument is required but its value is irrelevant (it can be `false`, 'foo bar', `42`, whatever). Regardless of the value, the element will be disabled, which is a hangover from ancient times when boolean attributes were added to HTML. Their presence alone does the job, they don't take a value (e.g. `<button disabled>foo</button>` creates a disabled button).

To unset the attribute (i.e. to enable the button again), use [*removeAttribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).

Comment: This code seems to work for one button. I edit the output to document.getElementById('0').addEventListener('click', clickFn, false);
where 0 represents the number of my first button. How do I modify the code to work for all buttons? It shall read the button number from id in the php code.

Comment: Can anybody help a little further on this solution?